# return type of the variable in Scala

Tags: scala, variables, types

How can i see type of the variable in Scala?

I have tried to do this like that:

```
val x = 10
println(type(x))
```

or

```
val x = 'Hello!'
println(x.type)
```

Bun unfortunately in both of these ways i have an error.

Answer (score 6):

Depending what you're trying to do, this might be sufficient

```
val x=10
println(x.getClass.toString)
```

However, this breaks down due to type erasue; Scala has more information than Java does and the above only gives you Java's view.  There's a [thread here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-how-to-know-type-of-a-variable-in-scala-td2222465.html) with more on this theme; outcome is:

```
def manOf[T:Manifest](t:T):Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
println(manOf(1))
println(manOf(List(1,2,3)))
```

gets you

```
Int
scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
```

wheras the `.getClass.toString` method will only get you an `int` and a mysterious `class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon`

Of course if you're using the REPL shell it tells you the (scala) type of things anyway:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_27).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x=10
x: Int = 10
```

Comment: In the REPL you also have the `:type` command (it displays the compile-time type of its argument without having to evaluate it).

Comment: Runtime class of `List(1, 2, 3)` - `::` - [is no so mysterious](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)

Comment: Maybe "opaque" rather than "mysterious" would have been a better description.